# Replace multiple words with re (case insensitive with parenthesis)

Tags: python, python-re

I want to write a function to replace multiple patterns with case sensitivity options. This is what I have now:

```
def replace_multiple_patterns(input_string: str, replace_pattern: list, replace_with: str, ignore_case: bool = True) -> str:
    for rp in replace_pattern:
        input_string = re.sub(rp, replace_with, input_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE if ignore_case else 0)

    return input_string
```

And these are the results:

```
replace_patterns = [" test", "my"]
input_string = "My sample Test string"
print(replace_multiple_patterns(input_string, replace_patterns, ""))

Result: sample string   

replace_patterns = [" (test)", "my"]
input_string = "My sample (Test) string"
print(replace_multiple_patterns(input_string, replace_patterns, ""))

Result: sample (Test) string
```

When there is a parenthesis in the input string, it processes is differently. I did some research and found some solutions for fixed characters but nothing for all possible scenarios.

This is the output I want to get:

```
sample string
```

Comment: Use `input_string.lower()` for the function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, it's a super easy fix. I made a slight modification to your code and it worked to create the output you wanted:

```
def replace_multiple_patterns(input_string: str, replace_pattern: list, replace_with: str, ignore_case: bool = True) -> str:
    for rp in replace_pattern:
        # Escaping the pattern for regex special characters!!!
        escaped_rp = re.escape(rp)
        input_string = re.sub(escaped_rp, replace_with, input_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE if ignore_case else 0)
    return input_string
```

As you can see by the comment, the only thing that's actually different is the inclusion of `re.escape(rp)`. Certain characters like `(` have meanings in regex, and your script failed to take that into account. [This function works to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)

This should resolve your request for a solution "for all possible scenarios."

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in  `(test)` are not treated as literal `(` and `)` characters but instead they indicate a [regex capture group](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#index-15) start and end.  In your example the pattern starts with a space and  `(test)`, for the purposes of this code, will behave the same as a  `test` pattern (note the space prefix).  That pattern will not match anything in the input string since `test` is not prefixed with a space there.  To match parentheses (and other regex control characters) literally you have to either manually escape them with a `\` or use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

```
replace_patterns = [" \(test\)", "my"]
input_string = "My sample (Test) string"
print(replace_multiple_patterns(input_string, replace_patterns, ""))

Result: sample string

replace_patterns = [re.escape(" (test)"), "my"]
input_string = "My sample (Test) string"
print(replace_multiple_patterns(input_string, replace_patterns, ""))

Result: sample string
```